# Numbers the form "123.456.789" after convert for Excel

Tags: excel

When i convert files .txt in Excel spreadsheets separate by ";", the numbers that were the form "0.12345678" become "123.456.78". I need that the numbers be the first form. How i do it in Excel?

Comment: It would be helpful to know *how* you are converting the files

Comment: **Import** the file and designate that column as **Text**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data was in a single column, lets say "A":

```
=VALUE("0,"&SUBSTITUTE(A5;",";"")
```

1) Remove unwanted character with `substitute`. Note that my decimal look like comas, not dot. You might want to adapt accordingly to your regional parameters. Same logic for arguments separators in formula, might be "," instead of ";".

2) Add 0. in front of that string, while this is still text.

3) Convert text to number.